# iOS using protocols and closing modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10.2

I have Navigation controller and a ViewController. let's call it `MainVC`. Now I am opening some ViewControllers in following way

MainVC --(Modally presented)---> VC1 ---(Modally presents)->>VC2

**Now VC2 gets some data and throws it data in below given way to VC1**

```
if let del = self.delegate{
             //Closing Current view controller 
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
            del.onDataSuccessfullyFetched()


        }
```

**However the Protocol is defined as**

```
protocol DelegateOnDialogDismiss {

    func onDataSuccessfullyFetched()

}
```

> Similarly **VC1** Throws its data back to **MainVC and gets dismissed like shown in above code. And then delegated method in MainVC  pushes a new viewController to NavigationView like so ...**

```
let popOverHouseHoldInfo = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idHouseHoldInfoVC") as! HouseHoldInfoViewController
                  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(popOverHouseHoldInfo, animated: true)
```

**Problem:**

> The MainVC is calling that function to push new ViewController in
>   NavigationView but it is not getting happen. I do not know why. But
>   everything is working as expected until the delegates tries to Push
>   newViewController but failed.

**My assessment:**  I think the main culprit is following line as we are dismissing Modally presented viewControllers :

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please help me. I do not know what is the main problem in this workflow.

Comment: (1) Are VC1 and VC2 both getting dismissed? (2) Does `self.navigationController?` return `nil` or a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: yes both are getting dismiss. When VC2 throws results back VC2 dismiss it self and then the VC1 throws data back to MainVC and VC1 Gets dismiss too

Comment: OK, set a breakpoint and check if `self.navigationController?` is nil. If not, you might be calling on a background thread.

Comment: no its not nil, i debug it

Comment: i made a delay in VC1.  after dismissing vc1 I am calling delegated method with delay. and everything work as expected

Comment: sounds like you should put the code in the `completion:` handler

Comment: that is really a good idea